# Is it possible to list cards horizontally?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-lists

Is it possible to order Trello cards horizontally in lists from left to right like books on a shelf rather than vertically from top to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You will need an extension to achieve this.

There are a number of extensions returned by the Chrome Web Store search: ["**Trello Horizontal Lists**"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/trello%20horizontal%20lists?_category=extensions)

I have no affiliation with either of the example extensions below.  You should review the different extensions that are available in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/trello%20horizontal%20lists?_category=extensions) and do your due diligence prior to installing any 3rd party software.

###### Example 1

> #### [Trello Horizontal Lists](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-horizontal-lists/bnjapjcicacmalbgnpnfgclacakagnli?hl=en)
>
> Turns Trello Lists Horizontal so they can be used for vertical comparisons.
>
> This is a simple plugin that converts a Trello board from listing cards vertically to listing cards horizontally.
>
> This has been built to enable vertical comparisons of cards across different lists vertically and introduces horizontal scroll.

###### Example 2

> #### [List Layouts for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/list-layouts-for-trello/aldklnbenbdgfgfbflalmlddkkndgnlc?hl=en)
>
> Allow Trello lists to be displayed vertically or in a grid.
> The List Layouts for Trello extension adds a button to your Chrome toolbar allowing you to toggle the Trello board layout from horizontal to grid to vertical by clicking the icon.